Swiper Js Slider is sliding more than one slide when scrolling on touched
Swiper is sliding more than one slide when scrolling. It works fine with the mouse wheel, but when we use the laptop touchpad to scroll, it scrolls more than one slide. How can we fix this? Please check out the demo -> https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mg9ssk?file=%2Findex.html
I'm encountering this issue only in vertical mode, and I suspect the problem is caused by the laptop touchpad continuously scrolling, which is why it slides more than one slide on a swipe.
I want it to slide one slide at a time with a single swipe from the laptop touchpad.
